# Error 500 while adding properties to open graph objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created some custom open graph objects and I would like to add some custom properties to them. I was able to add properties last week. However, since some days ago when I click "save changes" nothing happens and the console shows an error 500.

I have tried to add properties to objects from several accounts and I am getting always the error 500.

Am I doing anything wrong or is it a facebook error?

Comment: Even if you were doing something wrong, you should not get a 500 error – so I’d suggest you go file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working again, it was a facebook error.